# How to change content (text) of a html <p> element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set up a button via javascript by clicking on which the text content of an HTML  element (small article about an island) should change according to the user input (name of the island). And it works but incorrectly - text appears to be changed for a moment and then changes back to the initial value. How to fix that?

```js
const texts = ['a_text', 'b_text', 'c_text', 'd_text'];
const islands = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

function new_article() {
  var user_input = (document.getElementById("userinput").value).toLowerCase();
  var new_text_index = islands.indexOf(user_input);
  document.getElementById("article").innerHTML = texts[new_text_index];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> The map of East Frisian Islands </title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The East Frisian Islands</h1>

  <section id="mainsection">
    <article>
      <p id="article">initial text</p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <hr>

  <form>
    <p>Input the name of an island:</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter text">
    <button id="my_button" onclick="new_article()">Search</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The button submits the form, which reloads the page. Change it to `type="button"` so it doesn't submit.